# stop mod_rewrites from changing shared ssl address

Tags: apache, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [https redirect for Network Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686668/https-redirect-for-network-solutions)

I have functioning .htaccess file for SEO and 301s but now I am trying to get shared SSL to work.  The ssl url with my host has to be https://secure.netsolhost.com/mydomain.com/webpage.html and it works when the .htaccess is deleted but when it's there it rewrites the url to http://www.mydomain.com/webpage.html.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

That is my latest attempt.  I got it to work when I specified specific pages to not redirect but can't get an overall rule for ssl working either by detecting https or the secure.netsolhost.com

I have also tried

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}!^433$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

and many many other pieces of code that I either don't remember or was going in the wrong direction with.  Please help as I have been trying to get this to work for hours

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your %{HTTP_HOST} check isn't working if your host is already re-writing some server variables as part of the shared SSL rules they have in place. May be worth checking with them if they know which ones they are manipulating. Although in theory there's no reason this shouldn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```